# When is the pseudo-abelian envelope abelian?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Consider an Ab-category $\mathcal{D}$ and its pseudo-abelian envelope $\mathcal{C}$.  If necessary, one can assume $\mathcal{D}$ to be $k$-linear over a field $k$ and have finite-dimensional hom-spaces.  I am interested in conditions on $\mathcal{D}$ that will ensure that $\mathcal{C}$ is abelian. Are there any such nontrivial conditions? (For motivation, note for instance that the categories in, say, [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610552) are defined via such a pseudo-abelianization procedure.)

**Edit:** The answer below discusses the semisimple abelian case.  What about the non-semisimple case?

Comment: Notice that when taking the pseudo-abelian envelope you only add new objects which are direct summands of your old objects.  This suggests that it's only the appropriate technique for the semisimple setting.  I can't come up with a good way of making that precise, obviously if D is already abelian then it's pseudo-abelian envelope is as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A sufficient (but not necessary) condition is that the endomorphism ring of every object be semi-simple. See [Jannsen](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1150598).